# Why do I have to set the former selected item to null after its removal

Tags: knockout.js

When I remove a selected customer from my customer observableArray like this:

```
var selectedRow = self.Selected();
customers.remove(selectedRow);
```

Why do I have to set the Selected object to null explicitly...

```
self.Selected(null);
```

...because the next time I click the remove customer button the former deleted customer is still  returned from the Selected() observable??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming from your code snippet that you populate by saying `self.Selected(mySelectedValue)`.

In your code, you are removing the item from your array, but that isn't connected to your `self.Selected()` variable.

Comment: ah right that means to make to work as I expected it the array itself should have a current item. Thanks sound logical what you say.